# Adding Boost recipe to Yocto SDK

Tags: boost, yocto, recipe

My goal is having a Yocto SDK with included boost libraries.
Some of the libraries provided by Boost are header only but many others need to be compiled for my target architecture.
I'm quite new to Yocto so I'm facing some difficulties.
I had no problems defining a new layer for my webserver in bblayers.conf and appending packages in the local.conf for apache and php.
I was quite lucky to have these packages already included in the yocto krogoth.

The problem rises with installing a new packet not present (or fetched) in the normal version, as it is for boost libraries.
I found [this](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/5268/) resource on openembedded which explains that boost belongs to the openembedded-core layer and gives this recipe to add to the layer:

```
require boost-${PV}.inc
require boost.inc

SRC_URI += "\
    file://arm-intrinsics.patch \
    file://boost-CVE-2012-2677.patch \
    file://0001-boost-asio-detail-socket_types.hpp-fix-poll.h-includ.patch \
    file://boost-math-disable-pch-for-gcc.patch \
    file://0001-Apply-boost-1.62.0-no-forced-flags.patch.patch \
    file://0003-Don-t-set-up-arch-instruction-set-flags-we-do-that-o.patch \
    file://0002-Don-t-set-up-m32-m64-we-do-that-ourselves.patch \
    file://0001-correct-error-which-appeared-when-compiling-non-c-co.patch \
"
```

I'm quite unsure on how to use it.
Should I download the boost libraries and unpack it in some directory ?
Should I keep the tarball?

Reading some documentation this file expects some "file" resource, so something found on my local disk.
Also, where should i place the bb recipe ? Is there a default folder ?
From what I've read it doesn't really matter but is good practice to keep layers with layers, recipes with recipes and so on.

Then I should probably rebuild the image and finally perform a:
bitbake  -c populate_sdk

Could you possibly help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `meta` layer of yocto supplies version `1.63` of boost under `recipes-support`. As long as this layer is listed in the `bblayers.conf` you should be able to build boost 1.63 without extra work.

If a newer version is needed, you can create a `boost-{version}.inc` of your choosing and set the `SRC_URI` to your desired download. Though `1.63` should be sufficient for most usage.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I noticed I have already openembedded-core and meta-oe layers, but I don't think they contain by default the boost libraries. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Podarce Check the update. Boost is provided in the default layer.

Comment: So I basically need only an IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost" in my local.conf, right ?

Comment: @Podarce Correct, that should take care of it.