# How to configure which BOOST library files are included in a Yocto SDK

Tags: boost, yocto

My question is almost a direct extension of this one, which asks how to add BOOST to a Yocto SDK. ([Adding Boost recipe to Yocto SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465129/adding-boost-recipe-to-yocto-sdk))

I followed the answers to the above link and I can see that the full set of libraries have been compiled, but only a subset of these end up in the distribution. For example, I need certain of the "*-mt.so" libraries, but only some of the single-thread libraries are copied into the final rootfs archive.

Could someone please advise me on how to do this?

I am unfamiliar with Poky, so might have the wrong terminology - apologies!

Kind regards, Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can use oe-pkgdata-util to find out what you need if you aren't sure. In this case,

```
oe-pkgdata-util list-pkg-files -p boost
```

This will list the packages produced by boost recipe with files in them.

If you're looking for something specific, for this case, try something like:

```
oe-pkgdata-util find-path *-mt.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with Kevins answer, you can always say which files need to be installed. This can be done in the recipe files ( for boost may be add a .bbapend file and write which files you want to install by specifying them in do_install += " ")